# Text/Image responsive design

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I should build a responsive design with twitter-bootstrap where the buttons in a navigation have an image(icon) and text if there is enough space but if not, there should be just the image. Like this:

Big screen:

`<image1> text1; <image2> text2; <image3> text3`

Small screen:

`<image1>; <image2>; <image3>`

How could I do that? 
Thanks!

Comment: What have you done, but more importantly where is the question?

Comment: Does my edition help?

Comment: If you want a 100% Bootstrap solution you can use the [Responsive Utility Classes](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive), in case that does not fit your needs you can use a custom media query like : `@media all and (max-width: XXXpx)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few classes in Twitter Bootstrap that helps to what you are trying to do.

```
.visible-phone  
.visible-tablet 
.visible-desktop    
.hidden-phone   
.hidden-tablet  
.hidden-desktop
```

For example, if you want that the text in your icons must be only shown when you are on a tablet or in a desktop just use this layout:

```
<img src="..."><span class="hidden-phone">Text1</span>
<img src="..."><span class="hidden-phone">Text2</span>
...
```

You can see more information about this classes in [Bootstrap - Responsive Design](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive)